# "I need a widget/control" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, list-questions

I've seen quite a few questions asking something like "I used this control on platform X. Now I'm using platform Y and is there a similar control?" or "I need a control that is capable of these functions..."

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/14580530/211627
- [What Control(s) would you use to represent this MS Word "Control"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6738589/211627)
- [What's the best WYSIWYG editor when using the ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590960/211627)

These kinds of questions seem to border on subjective (falling more into the "I would like to participate in a discussion about" category then "I would like others to explain") but I've noticed that they are very rarely closed or even downvoted. Where should the line be drawn and should these kinds of questions be closed as "not constructive"?

Comment: This question title sounds like an ad for some weird S&M relationship...

Comment: @animuson - haha... you're right. I didn't even think of that. I'll see if I can come up with something better.

Answer (score 4):

I think the criteria should be on how specific the request is.
**A broad request generates a list, while a specific request generates an answer.**

Unfortunately right now, the broad questions should be closed as "not constructive", though a better termed reason would be great.

Comment: +1 by the way... best summation I've ever seen on broad/specific questions.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if the question is answered by a single link or a list of different links, if the question is answered by "use this [link]" then it should be closed.